# Get value of drop down in controller

Tags: php, mysql, yii

How can i get selected value of a drop down list in `_form page` to my controller page.

```
_form page

    <?php echo  $form->dropDownList($model,'prd_id',CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(),
'cat_id','category')) ?>
```

I want to get the value of selected item in drop down in my `Categorycontroller` page.

Comment: u want to get it before the form submit?then use activeDropdown

Comment: normally we get like this `$_POST[MODELNAME]['prd_id']`

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
  <?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList($model,'prd_id',CHtml::listData(Category::model()-  >findAll(),array(
   'prompt'=>'Select',
            'ajax' => array(
            'type'=>'POST',
            'url'=>Categorycontroller::createUrl('action'),
            )
        )); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need AJAX here:

If it is for a dependent dropdown then try this

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/24/

Even if it's not for a dependent dropdown the same principals apply with passing the selection to a controller.

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('country_id','', array(1=>'USA',2=>'France',3=>'Japan'),
array(
'ajax' => array(
'type'=>'POST', //request type
'url'=>CController::createUrl('currentController/dynamiccities'), //url to call.
//Style: CController::createUrl('currentController/methodToCall')
'update'=>'#city_id', //selector to update
//'data'=>'js:javascript statement' 
//leave out the data key to pass all form values through
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in controller:

First use var_dump after $_POST[MODELNAME]
then use

```
$rs = isset($_POST[MODELNAME]['prd_id']) ? $_POST[MODELNAME]['prd_id'] : array();
$value = (!is_array($rs)) ? explode(',', $rs) : $rs;
```